# Pandas dataframe lambda expression: can I use an AND operator in regex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have this dataframe and a regex pattern.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['base','rhino','gray','horn'],
                   'b':['rhino','elephant', 'gray','trunk'],
                   'c':['cheese','lion', 'beige','mane']})

       a         b       c
0   base     rhino  cheese
1  rhino  elephant    lion
2   gray      gray   beige
3   horn     trunk    mane
```

I needed to find a row that matched the regex pattern. This worked but then I realized that in production, the previous row also has one of those words ("rhino" in row 0).

```
pattern = '.*(rhino|elephant|lion)'
row_index = df.index[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)].tolist()
```

So I need to update this and find the row that has ***all of those words in the pattern*** (row 1).

I came up with a solution but it's not the most elegant. Is there a shorter way to achieve this?

```
def match_pat(df):

    def return_last(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return x[-1]

    a = df.index[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('rhino', flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)].tolist()
    b = df.index[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('elephant', flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)].tolist()
    c = df.index[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('lion', flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis=1)].tolist()

    a = return_last(a)
    b = return_last(b)
    c = return_last(c)

    if a == b == c:
        return a
    else:
        return 0


row_index = match_pat(df)
print(row_index)
```

The value of row_index is correctly 1. But is there a shorter way? Can you use an "AND" operator in the lambda expression to match each word individually?

Comment: Do you not just want `all` instead of `any`? `row_index = df.index[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)).all(axis=1)].tolist()` Or do you want to make sure that all three distinct values are present?

Comment: ah yes, I was focused on the regex and didn't think about .all(axis=1). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python sets for that:

```
words = set(['rhino', 'lion', 'elephant'])
df.apply(lambda r: set(r)==words, axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

And to subset:

```
words = set(['rhino', 'lion', 'elephant'])
df[df.apply(lambda r: set(r)==words, axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
       a         b     c
1  rhino  elephant  lion
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.extract`:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'.*(rhino|elephant|lion)', re.I)

out = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(pat).squeeze()).notna().all(axis=1)]
```

```
>>> out
       a         b     c
1  rhino  elephant  lion

>>> out.index.tolist()
[1]
```